# Memory files get trashed by third party software

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, file-io

I have an collection of apps that rely on memory files. I create them with a persistent app, then 3 apps update the files with GPS, IMU and switch data, and 3 apps read the current status and generate commands to servo controllers. This has worked fine for years, but today the apps failed due to missing memory files when I started a third party c# camera control app.

I suspect the other app overwrites the memory area. Is there a way to protect these memory files.

I am in  Visual Studio 2017, Win10/64 and .net 4.6.1

I have included the create and sample read and write code - all of which have worked for years. I did update the system to current .net 4.6.1, and without the 3rd party app the system runs for hours without error. The instant I start the c# app compiled app the memory files disappear. I do not have access to the source, and am hopeless with C#.

Not a clue now, one solution is to install a new CPU and run the 3rd partys app on a separate box. There is no communication between my apps and it.

```
I create with :

Dim LoopForever As Boolean = True
Dim AHRS_Memory_File_Name As String = "AHRSMemoryData"
Dim GPS_Memory_File_Name As String = "GPSMemoryData"
Dim Switch_Memory_File_Name As String = "SwitchMemoryData"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MMS = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(Switch_Memory_File_Name, 20, 
 MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim GPS = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(GPS_Memory_File_Name, 200, 
MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim AHRS = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(AHRS_Memory_File_Name, 200, 
MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Do Until LoopForever = False
        Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Loop

End Sub

A sample Write is 

Sub WriteGPS_To_Memory()
    Dim GPS_MMF = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(GPS_Memory_File_Name)
    Dim Bytes As Byte()

    ' This is the format of the current gps memory message

    outMessage = GPSSpeedIn & "," & GPSBearing & "," & GPSLongitude & "," 
     & GPSLatitude & "," & GarminMagDeviationText & "," & GPSMessageCount 
      & "," & GPSAltitude & ","

    Bytes = StrToByteArray(outMessage)

    Try
        Using writer = GPS_MMF.CreateViewAccessor(0, Bytes.Length)
            writer.WriteArray(Of Byte)(0, Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
            ' writer.Dispose()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("mem write error = " & ex.ToString)

    End Try

And a sample read is 

    Dim MMF = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(MEMS_Memory_File_Name)
    Using reader = MMF.CreateViewAccessor(0, 200, 
    MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read)

        Dim NewByteString = New Byte(200) {}
        reader.ReadArray(Of Byte)(0, NewByteString, 0, 
        NewByteString.Length)

        InMessage = Convert.ToString(NewByteString)

        teststring = ""
        CycleCount = CycleCount + 1
        teststring = BitConverter.ToString(NewByteString)
        For i As Integer = 0 To NewByteString.Length - 1

            AHRS_CommDataIn = 
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(NewByteString)
        Next
         End Using
          MMF.Dispose()
```

Best outcome is to find a way to protect these files. I am in the US, the vendor is in Israel and not particularly responsive.

There is time pressure on this as my company uses this software to locate water bodies producing mosquitoes (hate those pests) which distribute West Nile Virus, Denge and Malaria. Today we scrubbed a 300 sq mi mission affecting about 500K persons.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was apparently in the third party software - they issued a updated program the day we posted the issue to their support site - so we must not have been to only site with this issue